# JHipster 5 availability

Tags: jhipster

Is JHipster 5 (with Spring Boot 2) available to play around with?  I've noticed that there is mention about work on JHipster 5 in the release notes, but can't see any info on how to install/run a 'preview' version of 5.

Comment: It's now officially released

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use directly the master version, no need to wait for a release:

- `git clone https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster`
- `cd generator-jhipster`
- `yarn install`
- `yarn link`

Then, when you want to generate a new project, using master branch:

- `mkdir newapp`
- `cd newapp`
- `yarn link generator-jhipster`
- `jhipster`

Don't forget to update regularly the master branch, as the community is very active and there are new commits every day :-)

Comment: I can't get this to work, I thought that it was because I had v4.14.1 installed globally as per https://www.jhipster.tech/installation/
So I uninstalled and tried various permutations but I can't get a binary jhipster to run when installing from the master git version

Comment: I had similar problem because I mixed up installation with npm and yarn of global modules.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Windows, use npm instead of yarn (yarn seems to be having some issues on Windows).

git clone https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster

- `cd generator-jhipster`
- `npm install`
- `npm link`

Then, when you want to generate a new project, using master branch:

- `mkdir newapp`
- `cd newapp`
- `npm link generator-jhipster`
- `jhipster`

Comment: What do `npm link` or `link` word?

Comment: @ArenasV. The `npm link` which we run on the **generator-jhipster** package creates a symlink in the global context. Next when we run `npm link generator-jhipster` in our project folder, it will create a symlink from the global context to our project. When we run the `jhipster` command, this will allow us to use the generator from the repository's master branch (which is the latest) instead of the globally installed version of JHipster. More information can be found at: [https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link)