# When JHipster will upgrade to Spring 2.0?

Tags: jhipster

I have a quick look at the [Spring Boot 2.0 Migration Guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide). There are a lot of changes. It would be hard to do an upgrade on Spring Boot in JHipster. What is the JHipster roadmap for Spring Boot upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The migration to Spring Boot 2 is already done, in our current master branch. You can test it, by following this post: [JHipster 5 availability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48898465/jhipster-5-availability/48899481)

Or you can wait, there should be a beta release for JHipster 5 soon.

Comment: We're also waiting for Spring Cloud to have a stable release

Comment: I assume that it is related to the microservice portion of JHipster.